# What tags should I use in PHP DocBlocks

Tags: php, docblocks

Say for example I have my name as the author:

```
/**
 * @author: Jacques Marais
 */
```

How can I include my website, my license and my copyright in my DocBlock? Which tags should I use?

Also what tags is the most common tags and how do I use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
/**
 * Short description for file
 *
 * Long description for file (if any)...
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * LICENSE: This source file is subject to version 3.01 of the PHP license
 * that is available through the world-wide-web at the following URI:
 * http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt.  If you did not receive a copy of
 * the PHP License and are unable to obtain it through the web, please
 * send a note to license@php.net so we can mail you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category   CategoryName
 * @package    PackageName
 * @author     Original Author <author@example.com>
 * @author     Another Author <another@example.com>
 * @copyright  1997-2005 The PHP Group
 * @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_01.txt  PHP License 3.01
 * @version    SVN: $Id$
 * @link       http://pear.php.net/package/PackageName
 * @see        NetOther, Net_Sample::Net_Sample()
 * @since      File available since Release 1.2.0
 * @deprecated File deprecated in Release 2.0.0
 */
```

You can read the manual with detailed explanations [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.sample.php).

Answer (score 0):

Copy from CodeIgniter

```
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2011, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */
```